# Trying to dynamically embed one html page inside of another

Tags: javascript, html

```
<H2> Would you like to bounce an instance or application?</H2>
<form name="dropDown" method="POST">

    <select name="choiceDropDown" onchange="include()">
        <option value="1">Instance Level</option>
        <option value="2">Application Level</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="inst" class="outsidePages"><jsp:include page='Instance_List.htm'/></div>

<!-- END CONTAINER -->

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- end content -->

</td>             </tr>         </table>     </div> </div>

<div id="footerWrapper">     <div id="footer">Footer content goes here</div> </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript"> function include() {     var container = document.getElementById("inst");          container.innerHTML = "";

    container.innerHTML = " <jsp:include page='Home.htm'/>  ";

    }
</script>
</html>
```

So for the script above what I want to do is if the drop box changes then the div "inst" should change so that it is including a different page. The problem is when I try to do this it breaks. If I make `container.innerHTML = "Good morning"` or anything else it works fine. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Your code sample seems to have gotten messed up, so it's hard to tell what you're doing.  Can you edit the question and re-format that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code sample, I'm going to go out on a limb and say you want to use jQuery, specifically the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.  It makes stuff like this ridiculously easy.

```
<body>
    <a href="#" id="loadSomePage">load some page</a>
    <div id="contentArea">content goes here</div>
</body>
<script>
    $("#loadSomePage").click(function(){
        $("#contentArea").load("http://www.foo.com/content.html");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if i have some javascripts or jquery inside foo.com/content.html will it load those scripts also??

Comment: Yes, jQuery will detect scripts in the page being loaded and execute them.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am trying the same example to load 5 static file(5 different html files which is saved in a separate folder) to another file; But files are unable to load in that page. - Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing server-side and JavaScript code together.  The result of your code would be to replace the content of your div with the literal HTML `<jsp:include page='Home.htm'/>`, rather than the HTML content of your Home.htm, as you intended.

To do what you want to do, you will need to perform an ajax call to retrieve the new contents from the server, then replace the old contents of the div with that.

Using a JavaScript library such as jQuery, this could be quite simple.  Your `container.innerHTML` line would become something like the following:

```
$('#dist').load('Home.htm');
```

Comment: Is there a way i can preload it without ajax?

Comment: You could load it into another hidden div, and then just swap the visibility of each div, instead of modifying the content.